# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-901, SQLSTATE=58004, SQLERRMC=Invalid collation ID, DRIVER=4.21.29

Tags: sql, database, db2, dashdb

Trying to execute the statement

```
select * 
from RU_VARIANCE_HISTORY
```

but I'm getting the error

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-901, SQLSTATE=58004,
>   SQLERRMC=Invalid collation ID, DRIVER=4.21.29

Tried searching but unable to find the solution.

Comment: Is anyone has encountered this issue before, tried lot of things but unable to find the solution.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen if DB2 thinks the statement is really too long or too short.  Try adding a semicolon to the end of your statement - this worked for me with the same error.